# Modify sed so as to assign unique fileparts into variable

Tags: bash, variables, filenames

I have a folder with several different filenames, each with a common pattern such as the following :

SampleA-1.txt

SampleA-2.txt

SampleA-3.txt

SampleB-1.txt

SampleB-2.txt

SampleB-3.txt

etc

I want to use sed in order to get only the unique filename before the "-number.txt" part. In other words I want the following result :

SampleA

SampleB

SampleC

etc

And I want to assign the above in a variable (e.g SAMPLE) inside a for loop. So I have the following :

```
    for FILE in $HOME_PATH/*.txt
do
    SAMPLE=`basename $FILE | sed s/\.1.txt//`
```

which does exactly what I want but obviously only when I have the Sample*-1.txt files, not the-2 or -3s inside the $HOME_PATH. Essentially I want to delete everything after the "-" and assign the unique names into the variable. Can you please suggest modifications to my sed ? I am sure it is something easy to do but I tried several variations with no success so I am missing something obvious here.

Thanks in advance for the effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAR="$( 
    for f in $HOME_PATH; do 
        basename $f | sed -n "s/\-[0-9]\+\.txt//p"; 
    done | sort | uniq )"
echo "$VAR"
```

This loops through all the files as your previous example did, and truncates the `-1.txt` sections (except the `[0-9]\+` matches any number at the back).

This only prints filenames that match the pattern: the `-n` means don't print anything by default, and the `/p` at the end of the sed statement tells it to print if it does find a match

At this point, you have a list that looks like: `SampleA SampleA SampleA SampleB SampleB SampleB`

It then pipes the output to `sort` (in case they're out of order), and then to `uniq`, which removes any duplicate entries (note -- `uniq` requires sorted input).   This give you the output

```
 SampleA 
 SampleB
```

This is then assigned to `$VAR`

Answer (score 0):

No `sed` needed, using only [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for file in "$dir"/*.txt; do
    sample=${file##*/}
    sample=${sample%-*}
done
```